# Javascript: "Save" a .PNG from an url

Tags: javascript, html, png

If the user clicks Accept in the following confirm box, a .png pre-defined file should be downloaded.

```
<script>
if(confirm('Press accept to download the .png')){ 
 //code to download the .png
}
</script>
```

Comment: *"a couple different things from a few posts"* does not qualify as valid or decent research. Please provide links to questions or any code attempt at the task and explain what did not work in your case or what is not clear in each of them.

Comment: Ok, I will edit the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is twofold...

1. Download an image instead of displaying it.

This is done with the download attribute...

```
<a id="abc" href="some URL" download="some URL">Download Image</a>
```

2. Link the DL with a confirm msg box...

Putting it all together...

```
<a id="abc" href="https://ibm.box.com/shared/static/tpnmvjclp166xbtlqpx712d2qzlvpity.png" download="https://ibm.box.com/shared/static/tpnmvjclp166xbtlqpx712d2qzlvpity.png" style="visibility:hidden;">Download Image</a>



<body onload="if(confirm('Press accept to download the .png')){abc.click();}">
```

NB: I'm hiding the anchor link from view with style="visibility:hidden;"

Comment: Hi, I don't want to generate a button. The user should be able to download it by 'accepting' in the confirm() attribute.

Comment: Oh sorry, it's a confirm msg alert ok... let's change it!

Comment: <body onload="if(confirm('Press accept to download the .png')){abc.click();}">

Comment: How's that now? :)

Comment: Hi. I am trying this solution in my code as we talk. When I click accept, it just redirects me to the .png screen, it does not download it. I am using mozilla browser by the way. If you test it, does it effectively download you the file?

Comment: Yes, it downloads fine in my Chromium browser.

Comment: I have tested it in Edge and works fine. Thanks for the help.